# SwiftUI check if UserSettings DOB is default

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to set the date of birth DatePicker to allow a user to set it once and then it becomes locked.

I thought I would do an if statement however apparently DatePicker() does not allow .if()

So I thought I would try the following below.

```
Calendar.current.isDateInToday(Date($userSettings.dateofbirth))
```

However I am getting the following issue.

> No exact matches in call to initializer
> [image: script to check date of birth]

Now the default of DOB its set to todays date.

The goal is to make this section

```
 DatePicker(LocalizedStringKey("Date"),selection: $userSettings.dateofbirth,in: ...Date(),
                               displayedComponents: .date)
```

be only changed once.

Comment: if ```userSettings.dateofbirth``` is date var then you can directly use it like this : ```let isToday = Calendar.current.isDateInToday(userSettings.dateofbirth)```

Comment: Why not use `.disabled` on the picker if the date is already set?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson by default the date is set to today

Comment: Why would you do that when it will always be wrong? Make the property optional instead and if you want to you can always set the start value for the DatePicker to todays date.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson correct and that's why if DatePicker = today allow to be editable if not disable.